# Visual Studio calls post build events before building is done

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

Thus I can not do anything with the actual output of the build process, e.g. I'm getting "file not found" for everything. Any Idea how I can make VS wait until the binaries are actually created ?

Edit: calling:

> echo on
>   copy /Y $(OutDir)$(TargetFileName) $(OutDir)Plugins\$(TargetFileName)

getting:

> D:\Coding\WIP\KSPFlightPlanner\KSPFlightPlanner\bin\Release\KSPFlightPlanner.dll
>   1>  Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden.

(file not found)

File is there, path and name is correct.

Edit2: Also tried xcopy "$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(OutDir)Plugins\" and xcopy "$(OutDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(OutDir)Plugins\$(TargetFileName)", still the same error.

> 1>  KSPFlightPlanner -> D:\Coding\WIP\KSPFlightPlanner\KSPFlightPlanner\bin\Release\KSPFlightPlanner.dll
>   1>  0 Datei(en) kopiert
>   1>  Datei KSPFlightPlanner.dll nicht gefunden

---

> Error 3   The command "echo on xcopy "bin\Release\KSPFlightPlanner.dll"
>   "bin\Release\Plugins\" " exited with code 4.  KSPFlightPlanner

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to do with these binaries? What type of binaries are they? And especially, how are they built? And what does your post-build event do?

Comment: Usually Visual Studio *does* wait until the build is completed.  What *exactly* are you doing and how *specifically* does it fail?  As a side note, if you can avoid using post-build events I'd recommend it.  Depending on the build/deploy process there's usually a cleaner way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

copy /Y "$(TargetDir)$(TargetFileName)" "$(TargetDir)Plugins\$(TargetFileName)"

Comment: $(OutDir) returns a relative path such as "bin\debug\" (which the copy command doesn't seem to like).$(TargetDir) returns a full path (but you need to use quotes around it).